# Reading gradle.properties values from android config

Tags: android, gradle

I'm using the code below to place the Jenkins BUILD_NUMBER into the Build Config object.

I'd like to be able to default this value from gradle.properties but I've been having difficulty. 
From the docs, it seems like variables just override each other, but from inside this android conext I couldn't access any variables... So I have to use System.getenv()...

```
       android{
             ....

    defaultConfig{
        ext.env = System.getenv()
        ext.buildNumber = env.BUILD_NUMBER?.toInteger()
        ext.buildId = env.BUILD_ID
        println "Build Number: $buildNumber"
        println "Build Id: $buildId"
        buildConfig "public final static int BUILD_NUMBER = $buildNumber;"
        buildConfig 'public final static String BUILD_ID = "' + ext.buildId + '";'
    }
       }
```

Update: After playing with this some more I realized that when inside android{} I can access variables that are defined in build.gradle but not from gradle.properties.

Maybe there is a trick to getting at this scope, but I haven't found it yet.

For example: if I have a variable in my gradle.properties "foo=bar" and this is my build.gradle

```
def foo2="bar2"

println foo2 // works
println foo // works

android{

     println foo2 // works
     println foo // works

     productFlavors {

          println foo2 // works
          println foo // works
          tablet{
              println foo2 // works
              println foo // blows up 

          }
     }


}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with the access to the variables inside closure, but you might want to just create a function that returns the value you want and assign it to the buildConfig. It's probably cleaner to keep the defaultConfig clear of that logic.